# Hi All, I am getting following error when i am building wakaleo game-of-life project in jenkin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.397 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-12T14:24:54+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

i tried to update the POM.xml file with Jetty, but no use can anyone help to fix this issue as i tried a lot to install all the Maven plugins and still it is showing me the error at Jetty

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue when i specified this plugin in `dependency` section, then moved to plugins and it did trick

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.M0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```